# Slow macro when sheet is calculated that contain formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I made a macro which is perhaps the simplest I've ever made, but it takes almost 5 to 8 minutes to run. What am I doing wrong? What could be the way to make the running time short? I can't wait again and again to let it be done. Here's the code.

```
Sub AB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 2 To 20
For y = 4 To 50

Sheets("A").Range("b7").Value = Sheets("B").Cells(y, 1).Value
Sheets("A").Range("b8").Value = Sheets("B").Cells(3, i).Value
Sheets("C").Calculate
Sheets("B").Cells(y, i).Value = Sheets("C").Range("b1").Value

Next y
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I had to include "Calculate" for sheet C as sheet C includes Excel formulas.

Can someone suggest a better way than this?

Comment: Does Sheet C have lot of formulas?

Comment: @GowthamShiva Yes. It has. I'm plugging values from Sheet B into Sheet A and then copying answers from Sheet C to Sheet B. For a single value, It's done in a jiffy. However, when I run a loop for multiple values. It takes time.

Comment: instead of calculating the entire sheet C, just calculate the cell/range that you need. May b B1 in sheet C alone

Comment: Is it make possible that all other cells auto calculated as they are linked with this?

Comment: If you observe improved marco speed, then find out what all cells are required for calculating B1, and include all of them individually

Comment: Speed has been improved and ran in before a second but giving only one result again and again which means no calculating B1 again on every loop. Range B1 is depending on alot of cells hence impossible to add all those individually.

Comment: What is the formula that is in B1 currently?

Comment: B1 is taking ratio of the by add cell D1 E1 F1 and G1 to adding H1 and F1. Then each of these cells are depennding on other cells and the list goes on.

Comment: You are not changing anything in sheet C as per your code. Why do you want to recalculate?

Comment: Actually Sheet C is based on calculation which takes input from Sheet A and then gives the answer in Cell B1 in Sheet C. Hence, I need to calculate Sheet C everytime to get the answer for every loop.

Comment: I guess there is no other way out

Comment: 5 to 8 minutes sounds fast considering that there are more than 6000 calls to Excel. You should copy the whole range instead of cell by cell.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the situation where large number of cell were required to be copied and "=" for each cell proved to be too slow. For me `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` resolved the issue - not sure if it'll work in your case. Though, range = cell, e.g. `Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(10000, 3)) = Cells(1, 3)` should work just as fast.
Also, you may think of using like `Sheets(1).Cells(7, 2)` instead of `Sheets("A").Range("b7")` as a matter of "micro-speed-optimization".

Yet another aspect to consider is to use arrays as much as possible (for interim values) and  to write to cells, the final output only.

Finally, it's worth looking into [this article](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/) as we often tend to overlook some aspects of the code that slows down runtime performance.